# Change the color of the line into the Contextual Action Bar

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar

I would like to change the color of the line that appears onto the contextual action bar; to be more clear I will put an image:

[image]

You see the Light blue line just above the white area? How could I change its color? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should first create your own 9-patch image with the colours which you want to use. For example an image like this :

[image]

And after that in your application's theme you should add this (for Holo Theme) :

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/my_actionmode_background</item>
</style>
```

For `ActionBarSherlock` or `AppCompat` you should use :

```
<!-- AppCompat -->
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/my_actionmode_background</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBarSherlock -->
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/my_actionmode_background</item>
</style>
```