# How to change color of CAB title and divider

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar

I've searched all that I could but I still can't change color of title and divider of CAB to white. It was white but then somehow I changed it to black. Can anyone shine little light on this, how to change these to white and what determines these colors. This is my app theme

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"></style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/my_actionmode_background</item>
</style>
```

[Follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239978/change-the-color-of-the-line-into-the-contextual-action-bar) for information.

To change the color/etc of the text in a contextual action bar:

```
 public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
      //mode.setTitle("Contextual Action Bar"); (replace this call)
      TextView tv= (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contextual_title, null);
      tv.setText("Contextual Action Bar");
      mode.setCustomView(tv);
}
```

where layout/contextual_title.xml contains a single TextView with your desired color/size/style etc

Answer (score 0):

are you ready for some Hack, Sir?? -(guessing hack code)

```
ViewGroup vg = ActionMode.getCustomView(); // cast it
for(int i =0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++){
    if(vg.getChildAt(i).getClass().isAssignableFrom(TextView.class)){
       TextView tv = vg.getChildAt(i); //cast it
       tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);// or your preference
       break;
       }
   }
```

just that, it should work.. for divider, well you can check for a `View.class` who's getMeasuredWidth() is less that 5dp; like this

```
if(vg.getChildAt(i).getClass().isAssignableFrom(View.class)){
       View v = vg.getChildAt(i); 
       if(v.getMeasuredWidth() < 5){
       v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
       break;
       }
 }
```

Hope it helps